# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain fails with 887a0001

Tags: c++, directx-11, direct3d

When I attempt to create a device and swapchain D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain fails with 887a0001. I am trying to call this from my dll.

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));

sd.BufferCount = 2;
sd.BufferDesc.Width = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sd.Windowed = FALSE;
sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevelArray[2] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, };

HRESULT res = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevelArray, 2, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &swapchain, &device, &featureLevel, &devicecontext);
if (res != S_OK) {
   printf("failed to create device and swap %llx\n", res);
   return false;
}
```

Ive seen a few issue resolved by threading it differently but I havent had any luck in doing so.

```
__int32 __stdcall DllMain(void* baseaddress)
{
    Start();
    return 1;
}
```

The function start is where I create my window, attempt to create my device and thread the message dispatcher

Comment: Following Microsoft's documentation, this is a error code for invalid parameter data. There's a big chance of your error being caused by anything you've set wrong, check if your HWND variable is not nullptr, also check if your swap chain description matches your window, some values like the Width and Height being set to 0 is a bit odd, try to set your `BufferCount` to 1 on the swap chain description and try to use the NULL macro in place of your own defined feature level parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've checked the window handle pointer and it is not null. For the width and height being set the 0 [DXGI_MODE_DESC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb173064(v=vs.85)) (when set to 0 it will automatically set the dimensions) I alerted it anyway to the window width and height, with the same result. Changing the buffer count also had no effect.

Comment: Very weird problem, I would say for you to try and set `createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` to see if any message is thrown at the console with more information, I'm not sure if this is a problem caused due to the project compiling as a DLL, so I also suggest for you to try and go to your project settings and change the TargetExtension to .exe and see if it builds a executable.

Comment: Yep I compiled the image as an executable and it worked flawlessly (after reverting to my old swapchain description). I switched back to a dll and it still was throwing the same error. I also didn't get any extra debug information when creating the device with its debug flag.

Comment: Well, this let me out of ideas. I was really thinking your problem was related to your code, and not that you're compiling it as a dll, I've even compiled my own direct3d engine here as a dll to see if the same problem shows up, but it worked normally. So my last bet of what is causing your problem is your program entry point, try to remove the file that has your entry point from your project and press `CTRL+B` to see if the same error continues, if it does, then I'm sorry, I already don't know what more could be done, your only option left would may be using a static library instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you debug your program, you should see this in the output:

```
DXGI ERROR: CreateDXGIFactory cannot be called from DllMain. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #76: ]
```

This is expected as explained here: [DXGI responses from DLLMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#dxgi-responses-from-dllmain) (`D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` will implicitly create a DXGI factory)

> If your app's DllMain function creates a DXGI factory, DXGI returns an
> error code.

So, you must not call this from `DllMain` (this is anynay a very special place where some [black magic voodoo happens](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873).)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've read a bit more into what you have said and apparently even createthread can be risky. How else am I supposed to call my start function without hooking something inside the process to call it for me?